# How to use the word "less/fewer" correctly?

Tags: word-usage

I want to express a thought which sounds like "Rick has eaten 8 candies and 3 pieces fewer of a pie" which means that Rick has eaten only 5 pieces of pie. Does my sentence soung grammatically correct or maybe there is some other way how to formulate that thought correctly?

Comment: Is this the actual phrase you want to say?  Is there some reason you can't say "8 candies and 5 pieces of pie"?   Is there some reason that you need to formulate it in that odd subtractive way?

Comment: Yes. It is a math exercise. The idea is to ask 'How many pieces of a pie has Rick eaten". So I need to somehow formulate that condition that Rick has eaten 8 candies and fewer pieces of a pie. I'm just not sure how to make it sound right given all the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier if you keep the object that is being counted the same. It makes the comparison easier.

> Rick has eaten 8 candies. Susan has eaten three fewer candies than Rick.
>
> Rick has eaten 8 candies. He has also eaten three fewer pieces of pie than candies.

It might be better to phrase it additively

> Rick has eaten 8 candies. This is three more than the number of pieces of pie that he has eaten.